# Check if extension installed without notice on fail

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

The method JComponentHelper::isEnabled('com_extension', true); checks if an extension is installed and returns a boolean.

The function will also throw an exception notice it the component is not installed due to the self::getComponent($option, $strict); in the same helper class.

Is there a way to avoid the notice if the component is not installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your database to see if the component is installed and enabled.

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT enabled FROM #__extensions WHERE name = 'component name'");
$is_enabled = $db->loadResult();
```

if the value of `$is_enabled` is `1`, then your component is enabled.

Comment: For legacy Joomla 1.5.x the query is `SELECT `enabled` FROM #__components WHERE `name` = 'COM_NAME'`

Answer (score 1):

While realizing that this is an old question, it is also one of Google's first results and I wanted to share what works for me while avoiding extra database queries.

To avoid the exception you can also check to see if the entry point file of the extension exists like:

```
if (file_exists(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_extension/extension.php') && JComponentHelper::isEnabled('com_extension', true))
    {
        // Your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same function isEnabled and catch that exception, so if the exception is thrown then the component is not installed.

Comment: The exception is thrown automatically and there's no way to catch the exception without displaying the notice. Check the code of the method and see if you find a way to disable the notice.

Comment: +1 Stilero. I couldn't find a way to override the core error handling. The problem is that isEnabled tries to load the extension, which in turn triggers the core to raise an error via JLog. See JComponentHelper::_load() for more info.

Comment: Upon looking further into the core, looks like this behavior is deprecated anyways. The core JError::raiseWarning has been deprecated in favor of PHP Execeptions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

```
JComponentHelper::isInstalled('com_extension');
```